# Subview fail to show up after I set a constraint

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add a small overlay view on top of the image view with the text “Original”,which should only be visible when the user is looking at the original image.

here is my toggleImage function,when the user press on it ,the image View will show the original image(and a view with text "Original" will pop up)then back to the filtered image when the user lifts their hands.

```
    func toggleImage(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.minimumPressDuration = 0.3
    if sender.state == .Began{
        imageView.image = self.rawImage!

        view.addSubview(originalText)


    }else if sender.state == .Ended{
        imageView.image = self.newImage
    }
```

Now I want to set a constraint to the view with text.

```
    func toggleImage(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.minimumPressDuration = 0.3
    if sender.state == .Began{
        imageView.image = self.rawImage!

        view.addSubview(originalText)

        originalText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let bottomConstraint = originalText.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor)
        let leftConstriant = originalText.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor)
        let rightConstraint = originalText.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor)
        let heightConstraint = originalText.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(44)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([bottomConstraint,leftConstriant,rightConstraint,heightConstraint])
        view.layoutIfNeeded()



    }else if sender.state == .Ended{
        imageView.image = self.newImage
    }
```

the subView fail to show up now, how to fix the problem?

here is the screenshot of the simulator when the constraint was not set.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y45Dw.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the bottom equal to the top:

```
let bottomConstraint = originalText.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor)
```

Your view is most likely being rendered off screen / outside the bounds of a view.

Change it to:

```
let topConstraint = originalText.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor)
```